# Link URL to image or Title rather than echo link , retriving image,title and link from database in php

Tags: php, html, mysql

I am getting image, title and external URL from database, and display it on my page, code is working well, But i don't want to display URL, I want when I click image or title it should go direct to that URL in new window. My Code is

```
<?php 
    include_once("init.php");

    $msg='';
    $adDir ='./'.EDITORIALNEWS;
$qr = mysql_query("select * from " .enews) or die('Error in connection');
while($rs = mysql_fetch_array($qr))
{
    $adv = '';
    if($rs['adv']!='') {
        $adv = '<img src="'.$adDir.$rs['adv'].'" style="width:60px; height:60px" >&nbsp;';
    }
    $image = $adv;
 $msg .='<tr>
    <td>'.$image.'</td>
    <td>'.$rs['title'].'</td>
    <td>'.$rs['adv_url'].'</td>
  </tr>';
}

?>


<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Editorialt News  Lists</title>
<link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="headerstyle.css" />
</head>

<body>

<div class="tabl">

<table width="95%" border="1" align="center" cellpadding="10">
  <tr>
  <td width="35%"><strong>File</strong></td>
    <td width="30%"><strong>Title</strong></td>
    <td width="30%"><strong>Link</strong></td>



  </tr>
 <?php echo $msg;?>
</table>

</body>
</html>
```

Image, Title, URL are  adv, title and adv_url respectively.
I think the line added should be like

```
<a href= "#" onClick="window.open('<?=$adv['adv_url']?>', '_blank')"><img src="<?=VIDEO.$adv['adv']?>" width="98%"  height="90" alt=""></a>
```

but how and where to use it don't know.  Being a student I have keen interest in learning PHP through projects.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it like as follows:

Replace the following line of your code with my code:

```
if($rs['adv']!='') {
    $adv = '<img src="'.$adDir.$rs['adv'].'" style="width:60px; height:60px" >&nbsp;';
}
```

//My code

```
if($rs['adv']!='') {
$adv = '<a href="'.$adv['adv_url'].'" target="_blank"><img src="'.$adDir.$rs['adv'].'" style="width:60px; height:60px" >&nbsp;</a>';
}
```

Comment: I used the code as                                                                              '          while($rs = mysql_fetch_array($qr))
{
   $adv = '<a href="'.$adv['adv_url'].'" target="_blank"><img src="'.$adDir.$rs['adv'].'" style="width:60px; height:60px" >&nbsp;</a>';
    }
    $image = $adv;   '    But no use

Comment: what do you want to say? Check my edit, hope u will understand.

Comment: Now Code edited as you suggested        while($rs = mysql_fetch_array($qr))
{
 $adv = '';
 if($rs['adv']!='') {
  $adv = '<a href="'.$adv['adv_url'].'" target="_blank"><img src="'.$adDir.$rs['adv'].'" style="width:300px; height:150px" >&nbsp;</a>';
 }
 $image = $adv;

Comment: Keep it up, if you find my answer as best, you can make this answer useful by adding 1.